# Get bean of type and generics from ListableBeanFactory

Tags: java, spring

I have the following spring beans:

```
MyProviderA extends Provider<A>
```

and

```
MyProviderB extends Provider<B>
```

where `A` and `B` are interfaces.

Now I want to find all the beans of type `Provider<A>` from the `ListableBeanFactory`. I know there's a method `getBean` method, and I tried using the `ResolvableType` like this:

```
listableBeanFactory.getBean(ResolvableType.forClassWithGenerics(Provider.class, AImpl.class).resolve())
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe the problem is that in my case `AImpl` is the interface implementation. Is this possible?

This seems to work:

```
listableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(ResolvableType.forClassWithGenerics(Provider.class, A.class))
```

but not this:

```
listableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(ResolvableType.forClassWithGenerics(Provider.class, AImpl.class))
```

Comment: An interface is not a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the type of your `Provider` is `Provider<A>` and not `Provider<AImpl>` (or any other implementation). For example:

```
class MyProviderA extends Provider<A> {
   A get() {
       return new AImpl();
   }
}
```

vs

```
class MyProviderA extends Provider<A> {
    A get() {
       return new AImpl2();
    }
}
```

The implementation we're returning in both examples is not part of the class definition. Without looking at the implementation of the `get` method we will not be able to see any difference between the two.

The same goes for Spring - it will not be able to resolve your `Provider`s using `ResolvableType.forClassWithGenerics(Provider.class, AImpl.class)`

Comment: Thanks nyname00. Can you also tell mw how to get the bean of type `Provider<A>`

Comment: Try something like `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") Provider<A> pa = f.getBean(beanname, Provider.class);` and provide the bean names from your `getBeanNamesForType` call. The warning is there because there are no class literals for parameterized types in java (`Provider<A>.class` will not compile)

Comment: Wow that sucks.. i was hoping to make it with a single call.